# fetching the <input> element value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<table>` and some rows (varies depending on the query run ) where I can a radio button and some `<th>` and an `<input>` and I want to catch that `<input>` value for further processing so please guide me

my HTML code

```
<tr>
    <th>
        <input type="radio" name="assignRadio">
    </th>
    <th> <?= $nearestResponders[ $i ]->get('firstName') . " " . $nearestResponders[ $i ]->get('lastName'); ?></th>
    <th> <?= $companyName; ?></th>
    <th> <?= $nearestResponders[ $i ]->get('contactNumber'); ?></th>
    <th> <?= $presentCity; ?></th>
    <th><?= $distanceInKM; ?></th>
    <input class="selectedResponder" type="hidden" value="<?= $nearestResponders[ $i ]->getObjectId(); ?>">
</tr>
</table>
```

my jQuery code

```
$('input[name=assignRadio]').on('change',function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
    console.log($(this).next('.selectedResponder').val());
    console.log($(this).closest('.selectedResponder').val());
    console.log($(this).find('.selectedResponder').val());
});
```

as you can see I tried some methods to get the value but failed so please advise

Comment: Try not to include your php file, rather actually get the final HTML and paste it here. Making a replicable jsfiddle or snippet would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is due to the way you have to traverse the DOM to find your target element. It's not a sibling or parent of the radio button, so none of the methods you've tried will work.

Instead you can use `closest()` to find the nearest common parent, the `tr`, then `find()` the element from there, like this:

```js
$('input[name=assignRadio]').on('change', function() {
  var $selectedResponder = $(this).closest('tr').find('.selectedResponder');
  console.log($selectedResponder.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <input type="radio" name="assignRadio">
    </th>
    <th>Firstname Lastname</th>
    <th>Company name</th>
    <th>Contact number</th>
    <th>Present city</th>
    <th>Distance</th>
    <input class="selectedResponder" type="hidden" value="foo">
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <input type="radio" name="assignRadio">
    </th>
    <th>Firstname Lastname</th>
    <th>Company name</th>
    <th>Contact number</th>
    <th>Present city</th>
    <th>Distance</th>
    <input class="selectedResponder" type="hidden" value="bar">
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$('input[name="assignRadio"]').on('change',function(){
            console.log($('.selectedResponder').val());
        });
```

Comment: This selects the first <input> in the table and not the one that was selected..I have multiple rows and i need to the know the <input> of the row that was clicked